# Commits can't close issues on github remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have a remote repository on GitHub and usually fix several issues by using commits containing terms like "Fixes", "Closes", etc.  For example:

```
git commit file -m "Fixes #123 closes #123 lorem ipsum"
git push origin mybranch
```

However, recently issues aren't being closed by these commits. I have to close them manually on GitHub.

Is there something wrong with the commit?

Best, and thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought it was just me. You are indeed using the correct commit syntax as per the [GitHub page](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages)
But it will only close the issue when committed to the default branch. Which is the master branch by default. You can change your default branch if you'd like.